# I am trying to locate plugins from tinymce, but unable to find them

Tags: angular, plugins, tinymce

I was having old version of tinymce, and was using plugins in our lms system. However, when upgraded to Tinymce 6 Self Hosted Version, I am unable to locate plugins e.g. "boxes", "buttons", alerts, minibuttons, mtemplates etc. All of such plugins were there in old version of tinymce we were using. but they are not available in Tinymce 6. Our business users want such plugins.

tiny_mce_wiris print preview fullpage importcss boxes buttons alerts minibuttons mtemplates well stbuttons   importcss  searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality  visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media  template code codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists  wordcount spellchecker  imagetools textpattern noneditable help  charmap quickbars  emoticons autoresize

Please help

I am looking for some guidance or directions on from where i can get Tinymce plugins i have mentioned in the plugins above e.g.
print preview fullpage importcss boxes buttons alerts minibuttons mtemplates well stbuttons   importcss  searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality  visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media  template code codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists  wordcount spellchecker  imagetools textpattern noneditable help  charmap quickbars  emoticons autoresize

This is how it was looking in OLD version of Tinymce
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFKh5.png)

In TINYMCE 6, Its coming like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljINJ.png)